# My jQuery clones are not showing. How do you populate a div dynamically from an array and its values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to populate my feature wrapper with a list. Right I have tried getElementsByTag, but that just duplicates the node with no content change. Right now, my hidden style node shows up at the top of the list and then only the first 4 entries in the array show in the ui.

**My array**

Federal tax credit, 1,240

State tax credit, 620

MassCEC rebate, 289

SMART (under 25kW AC), 24

Net Metering, 16

**My Output**

Dummy Node That Should Bee Hidden, Dummy Value

Federal tax credit, 1,240

State tax credit, 620

MassCEC rebate, 289

SMART (under 25kW AC), 24

```
const incentives_array = data.user.Incentives_Array;

incentives_array.forEach((incentive) => {

 console.log(incentive);
 style with the "Sample Card" class
             
 const benefit = document.getElementById('incentive');
 const clone = benefit.cloneNode(true);
                
 clone.setAttribute('id', '');
 clone.style.display = 'grid';
                
 const check = clone.getElementsByTagName('check-icon');
                check.src = "https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/609831e7088fb22c2a678b09/60ca43b8a79f1ae728de8fbc_Check.svg";
                
 const benefit_name = document.getElementById('benefit-name');
                benefit_name.textContent = incentive.name;
                
 const benefit_price = document.getElementById('benefit-price');
 benefit_price.textContent = "+ " + formatter.format(incentive.value);
                
                
incentive_container.appendChild(clone);
                
                

 })
```

[Output UI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DKNZ.png)

Comment: Please include output text as text, not as a picture of text. Please also include the HTML on which the code shown runs. It would also be helpful if you could include sample data for the `incentives_array`.

Comment: @HereticMonkey My first post! Still learning the best practices. Post has been updated.